# reg query returning hexadecimal value

Tags: batch-file

In bat script I am performing below operation

```
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=    " %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\NICE Systems\Nice Screen" /v EnableEncryption') DO SET encription=%%B
Echo encription=%encription%
```

Its returning Hexadecimal value 0*0

How to convert that to numeric ? or how to compare Hexadecimal value in bat script ?

Comment: 0*0 isn't a hex notation. 0x0 would be a hex value.

Answer (score 4):

Batch can convert hex values with set /a.

```
Set /a var=0xe2
Echo %var%
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you only want to know the value without saving it in a variable:

set /a Hexadecimalvalue

ex:

set /a 0x25

Result:

37